# StringBuilder not printing its value?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, int, stringbuilder

I'm a noob to java, so I'm sorry if this is a simple question.

I always found it interesting that you could condense a number into a single digit by adding its digits together. Thus, I decided to try to make a program to do it for me! Here's an example.

> **Input:** 557
>
> 5 + 5 + 7 = 17
>
> 1 + 7 = 8
>
> **Answer:** 8

See! This obviously would work with any number. But, my program is terminating with no output. Can anyone help me out? I'm not so used to tringBuilder, so I think that might be the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class MagicNumberApp
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int number;
        String numberstring;
        boolean keepGoing = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        sopl("Welcome to Magic Number! \nThe idea is to add the idividual digits of a number "
                + "\nuntil it is condensed into a one digit number.\n\nInput a number...");
        sop(">");

        number = input.nextInt();

        numberstring = Integer.toString(number);

        if (numberstring.length() < 1)
            keepGoing = true;

        sopl("");

        number = 0;

        while (keepGoing)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberstring.length(); i++)
            {
                number += Character.getNumericValue(numberstring.charAt(i));
                builder.append("+" + numberstring.charAt(i) + " ");
            }
            builder.append("=" + number);
            sopl(builder);

            if (numberstring.length() > 1)
            {
                numberstring = Integer.toString(number);
                number = 0;
                sopl("");
            }
            else
            {
                keepGoing = false;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void sop (Object o)
    {
        System.out.print(o);
    }

    public static void sopl (Object o)
    {
        System.out.println(o);
    }

}
```

Comment: `keepGoing` is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `keepGoing` logic is backwards.  You are setting `keepGoing` to `true` is the inputted number is less than 1 digit and you initialized it to `false`.

```
if (numberstring.length() < 1)
    keepGoing = false;
```

All numbers have at least one digit, even `0`, so there is no need for the above test before the `while` loop.  Remove it.  But you must initialize `keepGoing` to `true`.

Comment: That's definitely it. The output is still screwy, but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in this line:

```
if (numberstring.length() < 1)
            keepGoing = true;
```

Right now it is saying that `keepGoing` will only be true if `numberstring` has a length of 0. You can change it to something like this:

```
if (numberstring.length() > 1)
                keepGoing = true;
```

**Edit:** I have an additional suggestion. You can add an `else` statement to print a message if the user input does has one digit:

```
else
    sopl(number + " only has one digit. Try again!");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the answers. I recommend you read your input as String and save yourself the initial conversion to string.

```
    numberstring = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: I actually did that for a reason. In a later revision, I added a try/catch for `InputMismatchException`.